# Chain rule not coinciding with direct computation with Multivariable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

> Given $f(x,y)=
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \frac{xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & x^2+y^2> 0 \\
>       0 & x=y=0
> \end{array} 
> \right.$

and $x(t)=y(t)=t$ and computation of $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} \hspace{1mm} f(x(t),y(t))))|_{t=0}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ but $f'_{x}(0,0)=f'_{y}(0,0)=0$. In this case the chain rule computation is not coinciding with the direct computation.

Is there a property or a necessary condition of the function, $f(x,y)$ that breaks the chain rule in the above case?

I have tried to approach this formulation by the definition of chain rule. Instead of directly plugging the value of t, the composite function can be differentiated with respect to the independent variable t as:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} \hspace{1mm} f(x,y)|_{t=0}= f'_{x}* \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} \hspace{1mm} x(t) + f'_{y}* \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} \hspace{1mm} y(t) $.

When $t=0, x=y=0 \hspace{1mm}, f'_{x}=f'_{y}=0$ then  $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} \hspace{1mm} f(x,y)|_{t=0}=0$ after plugging the following values.

But I am not getting that why on directly substituting the value of t in the above function yields incorrect results.

Please let me know if my approach to the above formulation is correct or does chain rule works on the concept that the functions should be continuous and differentiable at the given point?

Comment: I think you have an error in how you calculated $f'_y(0,0)$

Comment: @Andrei i computed it by using the limit definition to it was coming as 0 keeping x as 0

Comment: Calculate first $f'_y(x,y)$ at an arbitrary point, then set $x=y$, then calculate the limit $x=y\to0$

Comment: @Andrei ok thanks

Comment: Please note that the function is not differentiable at $0$

Comment: @Andrei ok thanks

Comment: @Andrei for proving the above function as continuous at 0,0 can I use the polar coordinate form and take transform the limit as r->0?

Comment: Yes you can. Just make sure that the limit is not $\theta$ dependent

Comment: @Andrei thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116517/discussion-between-ten-do-and-andrei).